# Is anybody else experiencing discrepancies between actual calls/renders and what azure wants to bill?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Since about a month we integrated a test report as a dashboard into a web application (power bi embedded). This dashboard is only accessible from within that application if you are logged on. We have around 20 tiles on the report and as far as i understood that, this means 20 renders. Since this is just a test and is mainly used to discuss with clients how the real reports will look in the future we had around 60 calls of that report in the last 30 days => so roughly 1200 renders. so since 1000 are free and we havent actually rendered over 2k it should still be more or less free - or maybe the $2,50 for 1000 renders.

but now our free trial azure account has been deactivated, because power bi ate up the free €170 start budget and it would total to bill around €600 according to the warning in azure... In my count that means azure counted 300000 renders. That seems totally wrong to me.

Do i completely misunderstand the pricing model? Anybody else have a problem like that?

Comment: this community is about programming, not server infrastructure discussions. You should've known that by now, please do the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I also had this problem, I was basically getting charged the per render instead of every thousand renders.

As specializt mentions, these kinds of questions aren't meant for stackoverflow.

To get the issue resolved, log a support ticket with Microsoft Billing from the Azure portal by selecting the question mark icon, and select New Support Request. Then explain your problem in detail and they should correct the problem and credit your account.